# Placing a list in the middle of another list using C++

Tags: c++, list, function

I'm currently working on a program that implements different functions to perform specific tasks on lists. The type list_t is defined to hold a list of numbers such as (1 2 3) and the empty list is defined as ( ). I want to write a function that takes in 2 lists, listA and listB, and an integer, n, as input, and then returns one list consisting of the first n numbers in listA followed by all of listB and then the remaining numbers in listA. For example, given listA = (1 2 3 4) and listB = (5 6 7 8) with n = 3, the function would return the list (1 2 3 5 6 7 8 4). I currently have functions to reverse the order of a given list, as well as a function that takes 2 lists as inputs and appends the second list to the end of the first, returning one combined list. Any ideas about this? I apologize for the long explanation

Comment: Homework? Otherwise use [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or [that](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list).

Comment: Haha yes unfortunately homework.

Comment: I have an idea, start with "a function that takes in 2 lists, listA and listB, and an integer, n, as input, and then returns one list consisting of the first n numbers in listA". Once you have that running, you can add the other features one by one.

Comment: @zaber Show us what you have got so far.

Comment: list_t insert_list(list_t first, list_t second, int n) {
       if (n == 0) {
               return second;
       }
       second = list_make(list_first(reverse(rotate(first, n))), second);
       return insert_list((reverse(rotate(first, n - 1))), second, n - 1);
}

Comment: I'm sorry thats a mess^, i can't figure out how to format correctly. The rotate call takes a list and sends the first number in the list to the end n times. Reverse just reverses the given list. List_first returns the first number in a list, and list_make takes an integer and a list as parameters, and returns a new list with the integer followed by the original list. Ideally this function needs to be tail-recursive. Im not sure if i need a helper function to do that